# Find value of returned Query-object using node-mysql in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using felixge's node-mysql plugin for Node.js. I want to find the highest ID in my database, so I use:

```
client.query(
"SELECT MAX('hits_total') FROM " + TABLE,
function (err, results, fields) {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(results);
    console.log(fields);
}
```

);

But how do I find the *value* of the result? The console logs:

```
    { 'MAX(\'hits_total\')': 
   { length: 39,
     received: 39,
     number: 2,
     type: 4,
     catalog: 'def',
     name: 'MAX(\'hits_total\')',
     charsetNumber: 192,
     fieldLength: 30,
     fieldType: 253,
     flags: 0,
     decimals: 31 } }
{"MAX('hits_total')":"hits_total"}
```

So I get one result, however I can not find it's value (which is 633 in this case).

If anyone can help me or point me in the right direction, that would be great :D

---

edit

Ok, so I've done some more testing and it seems that there is something wrong with the syntax `"SELECT MAX('hits_total') FROM " + TABLE,`

I can tell because when I change it to, for instance:

`"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE id=200"`

it suddenly returns a valid object:

`{ id: 200, hits_total: 102 }`

So maybe MAX('whatever_field') isn't supported yet? How can I find out, and are there alternatives to achieve the same effect?

---

another edit > I can't answer my own question within 8 hours, so here it is:

Right, I've found a solution.

Like mentioned, the syntax `("SELECT MAX('hits_total') FROM " + TABLE` for some reason doesn't return a useful object.

So instead, I use this syntax (I'll paste the entire block for completeness):

```
var hits = 0;
var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM hits ORDER BY hits_total DESC LIMIT 1");
query
    .on('row', function(row) {
        console.log("(row)");
        hits = row.hits_total;
    })
    .on('end', function(result) {
        console.log("(end)");
    });
```

The row object returned by `query.on('row', callback(row){});` has the fieldname(s) of that row as properties - in this case `.hits_total`.

Comment: Are you sure TABLE is set? This never happened to me before when using node-mysql, there must be something with your code.

Comment: TABLE is set, but to make sure I also tried by replacing `... FROM " + TABLE",` to `... FROM hits",` which made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`results` should be an array if it is actually returning the rows. In this case it looks like it is returning something else instead.

The issue is with your query, not with your code. You have single-quotes around "hits_total", so it is literally taking the maximum of a string. Remove the single quotes, or change them to back-ticks, and then it will process the string as a column name.

```
client.query("SELECT MAX(hits_total) FROM " + TABLE, function (err, results, fields) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(results);
  console.log(fields);
});
```

Comment: I switched `console.log(max);` and `max = row["MAX('hits_total')"]` because otherwise it would just log 'null'. Anyway, `"MAX('hits_total')"` is simply logged as `hits_total`. It doesn't log the actual value. Can it be that I set the field type wrong in MySQL? It's set to INT.

Comment: Seriously, it's the quotes around 'hits_total'? :o

Comment: Thanks, you are indeed right. The solution I posted also worked so I'm not changing it back, but your answer is correct :).